# Import specific function only from file

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have one file, `foo.py`

```
import UnavailableModule

class Bob:
    def useful_func(self, arg):
        # Do useful stuff (doesn't use UnavailableModule)
```

And in another file `bar.py` in the same directory, I need `useful_func()` but can't do this

```
from foo.Bob import useful_func
```

because it results in

```
problem: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

with traceback

```
C:\...\bar.py in <module>()
----> 1 from foo.Bob import useful_func
C:\...\foo.py in <module>()
----> 1 import UnavailableModule
```

Is it possible to just get `useful_func()` only by some other means?

Comment: Uh, firstly, `useful_func` is a method, so you must import `Bob`, the class in which it is defined. Second, when you import, the contents of the file are always run, you can't just get part of the file to run.

Comment: Also, you can't import anything `from foo.Bob`, because you can't import `from` a class.

Comment: Why is `foo.py` trying to import `UnavailableModule` at all? And if `foo.py` needs `UnavailableModule`, why don't you have that module?

Comment: @user2357112 It's a long story involving the Windows Linux Subsystem

Comment: Well, you're going to need to either get `UnavailableModule`, or change `foo.py` not to assume the module's presence.

Comment: Or provide an empty stub named `UnavailableModule.py` somewhere in `sys.path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `useful_func` is an instance method, you can import it with whole `Bob` class, like this :

```
from foo import Bob
```

then you can create object of `Bob` and use your function like this:

```
b = Bob()
b.useful_func('something useful i believe')
```

but this does not solve your problem. Your problem as I read is that import of `UnavailableModule` is run while importing `foo` module.

Well, it will be run, because that is how imports work, you can prevent this import with such construct:

```
class Bob:
  def useful_func(self, arg):
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import UnavailableModule
```

This will prevent importing your `UnavailableModule` while importing `foo` module from another module. However I am not sure whether this is good practice. It works though.